# Is my approach correct? Linear model, linear mixed model, or regular t.test?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, linear-model

**The experiment:**
I am analyzing samples from patients presenting two different diseases (e.g.: Cond_A, and Cond_B). I have 50 samples from each group. I have additional information about these samples, such as age, sex, and how long the samples have been frozen.
For the actual analysis, we used a technique that quantifies 7000+ analytes in each sample, and I want to determine which analytes are statistically changing between the two groups.

One last thing to consider, the assay uses a plate systems, where it can only fit 96 samples. Since we use calibrators and quality control, we ended up with 85 samples in Plate1 and 15 samples in Plate2 (of which we had Cond_A = 6, Cond_B = 9). Inter plate variability was "corrected" using median normalization and the calibrator samples.

**The company's approach:**
They use a simple t.test of Cond_A vs Cond_B. After multiple comparisons correction, using Benjamini-Hochberg, the analysis yielded 9 analytes statistically changing (p<0.05).

**My approach:**
I believe we have to take into consideration the plate as a batch effect. At first, I thought that a linear mixed model would be the way to go, but the plate has only two levels so it seems it should be considered as a fixed effect, and not a random effect. Since I don't know much about stats, I avoided adding all the other variables (age, sex, etc.). Therefore, I used a regular linear model in R: `lm("analyte ~ SampleGroup + PlateId", data = cleanData)`

It resulted in 236 analytes statistically changing, which is too good to be true. What are your thoughts? Does my approach make any sense?

Comment: You omitted the covariates so in that sense your analysis is incomplete and not yet ready to present as an alternative to the company's approach.

Comment: "*Inter plate variability was "corrected" using median normalization and the calibrator samples.*" ...  I don't know exactly what this means, but wouldn't this erase the effect of *Plate* ? ...  They used Benjamini-Hochberg correction for multiple tests.  Did you use any *p*-value correction ?  This could make a big difference if you are making 7000 comparisons.

Comment: - dipetkov: by covariates do you mean age, sex, etc? I don't know if this is a thing for this case, but I was afraid of overfitting the model. Not addressing covariates makes my model worse than the company's approach of a simple t.test?
- SalMangiafico: I agree with you, and I would assume that normalization removes the batch effect. However, I use a package in R to analyze another type of data where we also have batches, and in that case, samples are normalized AND batches are taken into account in the linear mixed model. I also corrected using Benjamini-Hochberg